# HTML5 Canvas Game - Controls relative to direction

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, controls

How can I make the controls of the player to be like, that left and right just changes direction and up goes forward, sowell as down goes back in the current direction, instead of the controls that I currently have in my code here:

```
<style>
.canvas {
border: 0px;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 1000px;
height: 500px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
</style>

<center>    
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
</center>

<script language="javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")


canvas.width = canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight
var w = canvas.width
var h = canvas.height

var player = {
x: w / 2,
y: h / 2,
speed: 5,
radius: 8,
vx: 0,
vy: 0,
}

var keys = []
var friction = 0.9

setInterval(draw, 1000/60)
function draw() {
canvas.width = canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight
w = canvas.width
h = canvas.height

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)

if (keys[40]) {
    if (player.vy < player.speed) {
        player.vy++;
    }
}
if (keys[38]) {
    if (player.vy > -player.speed) {
        player.vy--;
    }
}
if (keys[39]) {
    if (player.vx < player.speed) {
        player.vx++;
    }
}
if (keys[37]) {
    if (player.vx > -player.speed) {
        player.vx--;
    }
}

player.vx *= friction;
player.vy *= friction;
player.x += player.vx;
player.y += player.vy;

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, player.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
ctx.fillStyle = "black"
ctx.fill()
ctx.closePath()
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to apply rotation when using your left and right keys, it will require some maths to workout the new trajectory when then using up and down arrows after a rotation

Comment: Yeah, that's right, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365552/how-to-rotate-an-image-x-degrees-then-move-in-that-direction

Comment: Yeah but the player's vx and vy should be relative to the angle, I don't get answer for that on that question, but thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16599606/2252829 In this question I applied the vx and vy for the bullets but you can figure it out for the player since the math is almost the same.

Comment: No that question isn't what I'm looking for, the first comment is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
player.angle = 0; //Changes depending on the radians the ship is in - currently faces right, defined outside of this.
```

Then using this where you get your keys:

```
if (keys[40]) {
    player.vy += Math.sin(player.angle); //Reversed because y goes down as the screen goes up
    player.vx -= Math.cos(player.angle);
}
if (keys[38]) {
    player.vy -= Math.sin(player.angle); //Reversed because y goes up as the screen goes down
    player.vx += Math.cos(player.angle);
}
if (keys[39]) {
    player.angle -= Math.PI / 128;
    if(player.angle < 0) {
        player.angle += Math.PI * 2;
    }
}
if (keys[37]) {
    player.angle += Math.PI / 128;
    if(player.angle >= Math.PI * 2) {
        player.angle -= Math.PI * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that while you develop this game, it's more efficient to store things locally, like Math.PI, and create lookup tables with cos/sin values in it instead of always calling Math.sin/Math.cos.

Comment: Well, I just found out something, I can't change the speed if the player with this code...

Comment: Got any ideas about how I can do that?

Comment: X to shoot arrow keys to move

Comment: Would you even need a speed variable in this case if you have vx & vy? My assumption is that you are going for asteroids style controls, based on the game (and the question and my answer - obviously). Which is looking pretty nice, if I do say so myself.

Comment: It's fine I just came up with this:  if (keys[38] || keys[87]) { // Up key event
  if (player.vy > -player.speed && player.vy < player.speed) {
   player.vy -= Math.sin(player.angle)
  }
  if (player.vx > -player.speed && player.vx < player.speed) {
   player.vx += Math.cos(player.angle)
  }
 }